# Max and min with the help of inverse

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ be continuous on $[3,5], \quad f(3)=2$ and $f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^3}$.

Find max and min values of $f'(x)$. Show that $\frac{127}{63}\leq f(5)\leq \frac{29}{14}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being $f'(x)$ a decreasing function then 
$$\frac{1}{126} \leq f'(x) \leq \frac{1}{28}$$
By Lagrange theorem
$$\frac{f(5)-f(3)}{5-3} = f'(c)$$
with $3 \leq c \leq 5$. By the previous inequality follows the thesis.